# Question on PHP Array Build

Tags: php, arrays, build

I want to build an array based on MySQL query result.

assume dbArrA and dbArrB come from db query result. And they are both arrais.

```
dbArrA = (1, 2, 4, 5);
dbArrB = (A, B, D, E);
```

How can I build the $data as this, thanks.

```
    $data = array(
            1  => 'A',
            2  => 'B',
            4 => 'D',
            5 => 'E'

    );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [array_combine()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php):

```
$result = array_combine($dbArrA, $dbArrB);
```

Answer (score 4):

try

```
array_combine($dbArrA,$dbArrB)
```

**Reference:**

[array_combine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
$data = array();
foreach($dbArrA as $key=>$value){
  $data[$value] = $dbArrB[$key];
}
```